# What is the meaning of “bc” in physics stack exchange?

Tags: support, language

That’s all. This might sound stupid, but that’s it.

I got a comment on one of my questions. It read:

> Is your problem with the result or the Mathematical formalism? Bc you can easily show that the number of images is positive and arbitrarily large, which is the same as 'infinity', or in the, in the limit reaches infinity. You can simply let the first reflection be I_1, show that for every I_i there is I_{i+1} of the same size.

I am confused over what ‘bc’ means...

Comment: If it is a new post, I suggest to suggest an edit to fix it.

Comment: In this particular case, the usage is internet-generic, but there is indeed a [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) (though it feels a tiny bit dated now).

Comment: We strive for something of higher quality than Internet slang.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's internet shorthand for "because."

Comment: Ok....... So this question is completely time waste. Sorry for this time-waste question

Comment: @WebDevelopmentPro I would argue that your question is just fine, and that your time was wasted by whomever was too busy to write out a seven-letter word. No worries, no hard feelings, and happy communicating in the future.

Comment: @rob thank you for this.

Comment: There are [many others in the wild](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) (61, but some of the misspellings are left out here): *'Cause*, *'cos*, *’cause*, *’Cause*, *b'caz*, *b'cos*, *B'se*, *b/c*, *Bc*, *Bcause*, *bcaz*, *Bcaz*, *bcos*, *bcoz*, *Bcoz*, *bcs*, *bcz*, *Bcz*, *beazse*, *bec*, *becaause*, *becaise*, *becanse*, *becaouse*, *becase*, *becasue*, *Becasue*, *becauae*, *becaue*, *becaus*, *Becaus*, *becors*, *becouse*, *becoz*, *becuse*, *beecause*, *Beecause*, *cause*, *Cause*, *Cos*, *cose*, *couse*, *coz*, *Coz*, *cuz*, *Cuz*, and *cz*